# Finding which part of INSTR is not found

Tags: sql

How can I find which part of the INSTR is not found? For example my query below returns 70002 and 70001 in my results. What I would now like to do is find which part is not in the table. Here is a hurdle I cant get over. I dont want to see all the other orderItems in the table.

In my scenario here I just want 70000 returned.

Basically, which part of my string is not in the table.

All advice is appreciated.

```
SELECT
    orderItems
FROM Orders
WHERE 
INSTR('70002-70001-70000',orderItems)!=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to parse the string into a `SecondTable` and get the desired results with:

```
select *
from SecondTable
where SecondTable.OrderItems not in(select OrderItems from Orders)
```

But if you need to select from the string, assign it to a variable and modify the variable for each record in your Orders table:

```
set @str = '70002-70001-70000';
select @str := replace(@str,OrderItems,'')
from Orders;
select replace(@str,'-','') STR;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8d67fa/9

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orderItems
FROM Orders
WHERE orderItems IN ('7001','7002','7003')

SELECT orderItems
FROM Orders
WHERE orderItems NOT IN ('7001','7002','7003')
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Metaphor's answer, the `IN` statement is most likely the better way. If, however, you want to continue using `INSTR`, only returning the missing values should be simple.

If you find the entries that do exist by checking if the return if `INSTR` is not equal to 0, then the missing entries are where `INSTR` returns 0.

```
SELECT
    orderItems
FROM Orders
WHERE 
INSTR('70002-70001-70000',orderItems)=0
```

Comment: Ok this gives me all the other order items such as 60004 70589 32560 etc. Im hoping to reveal which number(s) in my string are not in orderItems. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3338724 looks like Rom Smith's answer should give you what you're looking for.